# jquery loaded file still in cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a part of my website I have last minute information, which should show up on ever page.

To do this I have a file named "LM_overzicht.html" which I load and display in a div like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#LM2").load("LM_overzicht.html")

    });


<div id="LM2"></div>
```

But when I change 'LM_overzicht.html'  the changes won't show up when I refresh a page, only ctrl+F5 will do the trick.
So I put in some other tricks which I got from stackoverflow

```
first this part in HTML:
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

But still it don't show the changes after a refresh. 
I also tried another trick in JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        // Disable caching of AJAX responses
        cache: false
    });

    $("#LM2").load("LM_overzicht.html")

    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't clear the cache either. Anyone an idea how to fix this?

my site: [Link to my site, where this 'last minute' part is at the bottom of the page](https://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm/spa_wellness_arrangementen/high-beauty-luxe-beautyfarm-uitje.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a timestamp behind the file so it never gets cached.

For example `LM_overzicht.html?t=1`

So append a generated timestamp with JavaScript. Note that this way the HTML file will never get cached, which I dont recommend. If you still want to do so, you could always just append the day instead of the whole timestamp..

Example code to prevent caching:

```
$("#LM2").load("LM_overzicht.html?t=" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
```